# how to get all Table's name in sql server ,access and oracle in c# code?

Tags: c#

how I can get all Table's name in sql server ,access and oracle in c# code ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

This returns a resultset that can be accessed from your C# code with the standard `SqlDataReader`, `DataSet` etc.

(It should work for any database that supports the ANSI standard [information_schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) views. I'm pretty certain that Access doesn't support them. Not sure about Oracle.)

Comment: thank's alot, but i see only the tables of Master.
how I can see all the table's of all the database's ?

Comment: I suppose you'd need to query against the different databases: `SELECT * FROM FirstDB.information_schema.tables`, `SELECT * FROM SecondDB.information_schema.tables` etc (or `UNION` those queries into a single resultset).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the SqlConnection object.

```
SqlConnection sn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
cn.Open();
DataTable dt = cn.GetSchema("Tables");
```

This will work for SQL Server.  Don't know if it will work for Access, and it will definitely not work for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle: `select * from sys.all_tables`

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of records in SQL showing all table names you can use the query; "show tables"

if thats what you meant?